# Redirection not working on componentWillMount() react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

```
componentWillMount() {
    var user = UserService.findAll();
    if (user.length > 0) Actions.home();
  }
```

where 'home' is `Scene` key in my `router.js`.

On the other hand

```
    onButtonPress() {
        var user = UserService.findAll();
        if (user.length > 0) Actions.home();
      }
```

worked like a charm !

My `router.js`

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router showNavigationBar={false}>
      <Stack key="root">
        <Scene key="auth" hideNavBar={true}>
          <Scene key="login" component={Login} />
        </Scene>

        <Scene key="home" component={Home} hideNavBar={true}/>
        <Scene key="pdf" component={Pdf} hideNavBar={true} />
      </Stack>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when the `componentWillMount` fires?

Comment: no error, I tried timeout and it worked but its not what i won't because it render the screen

Comment: To be able to help it'd be great if you can explain the flow of your process. If this is the start of the application (launch) and a user is directed to home if logged-in or auth if they need to login then i suggest moving the logic outside of your home component into a launch screen that does that check while app is intialising and directs the user to the right scene.

Comment: I am doing this on my launch screen only... I mean I don't have any splash screen. I either have log-in or home as an starting point. To sum up, here launch screen is login screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`on` props did the trick for me

I need conditional navigation, so I used `success` and `failure` attributes with names of scenes to navigate

I am posting my code below, hope it helps someone

```
<Scene
    key="login"
    component={Login}
    on={() => UserService.findAll().length > 0}
    success={()=>
       Actions.replace("home")
    }  
    failure="login"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay from what I can assume you are trying to fetch or check local storage for user data in your UserService. What I would suggest is not to try and stop the component from rendering or "mounting" using the lifecycle hook `componentWillMount`. Instead you can render an `ActivityIndicator` while the `UserService.findAll()` is finding the user (controlled by the state) since you do not want to the component to render until the UserService is done with the user finding process.

something like that

In you constructor assign a value that will be used to either render an `ActivityIndicator` or the component (I'm assuming the `login` component). Let's call it `searching` for example:

```
// in your constructor
this.state = {
  searching : true;
}

// assuming it is an async function
async componentWillMount(){
  var user = await UserService.findAll();
  if (user.length > 0) {
    Actions.home({type : ActionConst.REPLACE}); // no need to update the state here as we will navigate to another screen resetting the navigation stack
  }else {
    this.setState({
      searching : false
    });
  }
}

// other methods etc

render(){
  return this.state.searching ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <Login />
}
```

of course that's an abstract of the render method but you get the gist :)

Comment: thank you for you answer, but Userservice.findAll() is not taking any time. Its synchronous method. When I put my debugger on this line :  `if (user.length > 0) Actions.home();` I get `Actions` undefined. @Mohammad Abbas, I will try your code and will update you

Comment: Okay let me know how you go with it :)

Comment: no, it didn't work :( anyways thank you so much for the help